# FREEBSD - How to backup permission recursively?

Tags: freebsd, access-control-list

How to backup permission recursively from folder, subfolders and files? I try using `getfacl -R /xxx > permissions.acl`, but freebsd not accept -R.

Have another way to do this?

Comment: `mtree` utility is a traditional tool.